# Why is there no overflow scrollbar showing on my messaging UI?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building my little Messaging UI and I seem to have a problem.

I have my container which has an undertermined height, but has 80px and 60px at the top and the bottom. So, to get the middle section height, I do `calc(100% - 140px)`. This is the right size. However, my content overflows at the top and no scrollbar seems to appear. I don't get why this is happening and I don't know how I could fix this.

Do you have any idea?

```
<div class="tw-w-full tw-h-full tw-flex tw-flex-col" style="">
   <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-row tw-justify-between tw-items-center tw-px-4" style="height: 80px; background-color: rgba(67, 67, 73, 0.8); color: white;">
      <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-row">
         <div class="tw-rounded-full" style="height: 60px; width: 60px;"><img class="tw-h-full tw-w-full" src=""></div>
         <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-justify-center tw-ml-2"><span class="tw-underline hover:tw-no-underline tw-cursor-pointer">assad</span><span class="tw-text-xs">Employeur</span></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-space-y-2 tw-justify-end p-3 tw-flex-1" style="height: calc(100% - 140px);overflow-y: scroll;">
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl mr-auto tw-bg-aa-yellow" style="max-width: 70%;">teste teste</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">asdasd</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">tessad</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">blablablae</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">Ceci est une question simple!</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">Bonjour</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">asdsd</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">asdasdsa</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">gg!</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">asdasd</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">asdasdasdasd</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">asdasdsadasd</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl ml-auto tw-bg-gray-300" style="max-width: 70%;">asdasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasd</p>
      <p class="p-2 px-3 tw-rounded-2xl mr-auto tw-bg-aa-yellow" style="max-width: 70%;">asdasdsad</p>
   </div>
   <div style="min-height: 60px; background-color: rgba(67, 67, 73, 0.8);"><input type="text" value=""><input type="submit"></div>
</div>
```

Those are Tailwind classes, they are a single use type of class. (tw-flex is ONLY display:flex, etc.) You can understand them pretty easily by only the title.

[image: can't scroll]

Answer (score 0):

the calc function with 100% inside is inscreasing your containers height, as height 100% is relative to its content.

you need to either set a max-height property or set a different calc function. maybe trying with vh (view/display height) instead of %.